# How to make a secure WCF Service with AD FS

Tags: wcf, wif, adfs

I'm trying to add claims-based security on a WCF service, using ADFS. I've succesfully done so for a Web Application (Passive federation), but I find myself stuck due to lack of documentation on the subject.

I've been playing with the Web.Config files to make it work... however, I just seem to be going from one problem to the next. Here's the Security Part of the client side web.config:

```
   <system.serviceModel>
      <behaviors>
         <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior>
            <clientCredentials>
              <serviceCertificate>
                <authentication certificateValidationMode="None"/>
              </serviceCertificate>
            </clientCredentials>
          </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
      </behaviors> 
        <bindings>
            <ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WS2007FederationHttpBinding_IService1">
                    <security mode="Message">
                        <message>
                            <issuer address="https://myIssuer/adfs/services/trust/13/windows" binding="basicHttpsBinding" />
                            <issuerMetadata address="https://myIssuer/adfs/services/trust/mex" />
                            <tokenRequestParameters>
                                <trust:SecondaryParameters xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">
                                    <trust:KeyType xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/SymmetricKey</trust:KeyType>
                                    <trust:KeySize xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">256</trust:KeySize>
                                    <trust:KeyWrapAlgorithm xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p</trust:KeyWrapAlgorithm>
                                    <trust:EncryptWith xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc</trust:EncryptWith>
                                    <trust:SignWith xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#hmac-sha1</trust:SignWith>
                                    <trust:CanonicalizationAlgorithm xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#</trust:CanonicalizationAlgorithm>
                                    <trust:EncryptionAlgorithm xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc</trust:EncryptionAlgorithm>
                                </trust:SecondaryParameters>
                            </tokenRequestParameters>
                        </message>
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost/Services/Service1.svc"
                binding="ws2007FederationHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WS2007FederationHttpBinding_IService1"
                contract="ServiceRef.XISecurity.IService1" name="WS2007FederationHttpBinding_IService1" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

I'm unsure if I'm using the correct binding type or endpoint here. When I run the following code:

```
     Service1Client obj = new Service1Client();
     string str = obj.GetData(5);
```

I get the following exception:

> Addressing Version 'AddressingNone (http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none)' is not supported.

Here's my web.config on the server side

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    <add key="ida:FederationMetadataLocation" value="https://myIssuer/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml" />
    <add key="ida:ProviderSelection" value="productionSTS" />
  </appSettings>
  <location path="FederationMetadata">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
          <serviceCredentials useIdentityConfiguration="true">
            <!--Certificate added by Identity and Access Tool for Visual Studio.-->
            <serviceCertificate findValue="CN=localhost" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" />
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add scheme="http" binding="ws2007FederationHttpBinding" />
      <!--<add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />-->
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <bindings>
      <ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
        <binding name="">
          <security mode="Message">
            <message>
              <issuerMetadata address="https://myIssuer/adfs/services/trust/mex" />
            </message>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration>
      <audienceUris>
        <add value="http://localhost:2017/Service1.svc" />
      </audienceUris>
      <issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry">
        <authority name="http://myIssuer/adfs/services/trust">
          <keys>
            <add thumbprint="7502424014D0A1BD87A5DEEF0D1EB13390101F07" />
          </keys>
          <validIssuers>
            <add name="http://myIssuer/adfs/services/trust" />
          </validIssuers>
        </authority>
      </issuerNameRegistry>
      <!--certificationValidationMode set to "None" by the the Identity and Access Tool for Visual Studio. For development purposes.-->
      <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None" />
    </identityConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel>
</configuration>
```

My first question is: is there a good, step by step tutorial on how to set up my web.config files for that? Ideally one with .NET 4.5?

Second question: I'm really confused about which binding ADFS endpoint or binding to use. Here's what it's currently set to.

```
<issuer address="https://myIssuer/adfs/services/trust/13/windows" binding="basicHttpsBinding" />
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your second question you can find some information on endpoints at [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adfs2-help-endpoints(WS.10).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adfs2-help-endpoints%28WS.10%29.aspx).  An endpoint basically specifies an address that you can use to communicate with the ADFS server. The type of endpoint will also tell you some things about its requirements such as whether you need to provide a certificate or a username.
There is also a mapping between endpoints and WIF bindings at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alikl/archive/2011/10/01/how-to-use-ad-fs-endpoints-when-developing-claims-aware-wcf-services-using-wif.aspx. This has been helpful to me when I have been using code instead of the configuration file to communicate with the endpoint.